# TexMaker biber: Cannot find control file 'bib1.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, biber, texmaker

I tried to compile a simple project with TexMaker but I do not succeed to deal with the bibliography. I have the error: "Cannot find control file 'bib1.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?"

I saw several discussion on this topic but none of them helped me.

My project is organized as follows: \

```
project_tmp
├── biblio
│   ├── bib1.bib
│   └── bib2.bib
├── main.tex
└── part
    ├── chapter_1
    │   └── chap1.tex
    ├── chapter_2
    │   └── chap2.tex
    └── part1.tex
```

My main file is main.tex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[backend=biber, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{{biblio/bib1.bib}}
\addbibresource{{biblio/bib2.bib}}
\title{tmp}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
blabalaanlaja
\subfile{part/part1}
\section{conclusion}
ezvzgzre~\cite{barnes_heat_2006,battista_turbulent_1970}

\end{document}
```

I use TexMaker and replaced the biblatex compilation line in the configure option `bibtex %` by `biber %`. To compile the project, I run `pdflatex main.tex` then `biber bib1.bib`. Here is the problem: If I define the main.tex as master document I obtain the following message:

> Process started
>
> INFO - This is Biber 2.9 INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg' INFO - Reading
> 'main.bcf' INFO - Found 4 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing
> section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '{biblio/bib1.bib}'
> for section 0
>
> ERROR - Cannot find '{biblio/bib1.bib}'! INFO - ERRORS: 1

If I do not define the main.tex as master document I obtain:

> Process started
>
> INFO - This is Biber 2.9 INFO - Logfile is 'bib1.blg'
>
> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'bib1.bcf'! - did you pass the
> "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

The file bib1.blg gives:

> [0] Config.pm:302> INFO - This is Biber 2.9 [0] Config.pm:305> INFO -
> Logfile is 'bib1.blg' [15] biber:313> INFO - === mer. juin 23, 2021,
> 16:10:14 [32] Utils.pm:185> ERROR - Cannot find control file
> 'bib1.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
> [32] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1

The file main.blg gives:

> [0] Config.pm:302> INFO - This is Biber 2.9 [0] Config.pm:305> INFO -
> Logfile is 'main.blg' [15] biber:313> INFO - === mer. juin 23, 2021,
> 15:28:21 [26] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading 'main.bcf' [61]
> Biber.pm:857> INFO - Found 4 citekeys in bib section 0 [68]
> Biber.pm:3981> INFO - Processing section 0 [74] Biber.pm:4154> INFO -
> Looking for bibtex format file '{biblio/bib1.bib}' for section 0 [86]
> Utils.pm:185> ERROR - Cannot find '{biblio/bib1.bib}'! [86]
> Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1

I tried to remove the auxilliary files before compiling and to close TexMaker and open it again without any success.

Few days ago, it was functioning but I had issues with another project so I tested few thing and the command `\addbibressource\{subfix{bibliography_file.bib}}` did not works so I reinstalled biber. Can this be the cause of my problems ? Could you please help me to solve it ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: you have two brace groups in  `\addbibresource{{biblio/bib1.bib}}` remove one of them.

Comment: I removed one of the brace group and tried to recompile and it solves my problem.

Comment: did you remove the bcf and recompiled really from scratch? Btw: your biber version looks quite old. Oh, and better try first without this subfiles setup. That only makes things complicated.